# 120v receptacle measuring 220v

Tags: electrical

I have a 120v 20a receptacle that is measuring 220V at the outlet:

[image]

In the panel this circuit is controlled by a double pole 30amp breaker:

[image: Breaker]

I was using a 120V window AC unit in this outlet and it was working fine for years.  How is this possible?  The unit recently started having problems and I was looking to replace it with a 220V unit.  Can I do that with the current configuration?  What else do I need to consider (wire gauge and amperage needs of the new unit come to mind)?

Here is the wiring of the receptacle:

[image]

Edit:
Here is [image: the cord] the cord on the unit I'm replacing it with showing it as 25amp.

And this is a link to the [replacement unit](https://www.appliancepartscompany.com/product/11231244) in question

Comment: Did the old unit accept either 120 or 240V, possibly via switches or jumpers?  It sounds like someone re-wired the outlet for 240V but neglected to change the cord and plug to the proper type.

Comment: If you're able to show pictures of both the breaker panel, and the back of the outlet box (turn off the breaker and pull out the plug, but leave the wires connected as they are), that would help us figure out what's going on.

Comment: Are sure it has been 120 in the past (someone could have used a 120 outlet on a 240 circuit) the normal case for a double pole feeding 120 circuits is you can have 1 circuit on the top receptacle and a different circuit on the bottom (I used to do kitchens this way). I am wondering if it has been this way or someone has rewwired a multi wire branch circuit wrong (this will destroy most 120v appliances in seconds. More info is needed.

Comment: @NateStrickland I added a picture of the back of the outlet with the existing wiring.  What exactly do you want to see in the panel?

Comment: @EdBeal The wiring on the outlet has not changed in the 6 years I've owned the property.  For the last 4 I've been running a 120V AC unit off this receptical (a LG LW1214ER).  I agree, I do not understand how the LG unit was not fried immediately.

Comment: Can you post a photo that looks into the back of the box, and also a photo that shows the front of the receptacle?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel The front of the receptacle is in the OP, I edited to add the back of the box.

Comment: So it has always been wired 240 with the wrong receptacle, air conditioners have several values on the name plate 1 is the maximum breaker size , The current draw RLA not fla as most motors use. RLA is the total system power requirement, there should be a minimum circuit ampacity rla x 1.25% . This is an area that trips up many folks the rla x 1.25 may not be enough to start the compressor, code allows increasing the breaker size without increasing the wire size (this being a dedicated circuit) if the RLA x 1.25 is less than 20 amps it would be legal to have #12 wire with a 30 amp breaker.

Comment: Is that a stub of a red wire in the box?   Is it possible that 240 was run out here once, and the wrong phase/wire was removed and used back at the panel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've noticed, someone has wired this 20A 120V receptacle for 240V at 30A.  That is very dangerous, and it's quite lucky your house never burned down.  Most likely your old AC was designed to accept either 120 or 240V, and so it didn't notice the difference.

Based on your pictures of the current wiring, I believe you have 10 gauge wires (wire looks like orange sheathed NM) which can handle the 30A it's breakered for.  It would be wise to double-check this with a wire gauge before upgrading to a larger air conditioner though.

To replace the current unit with one that requires 30A of 240V, assuming you already have 10 gauge wire in the wall, you'll only need to change the receptacle to the correct one, such as a NEMA 6-30.  Or, if your new AC wants 20A of 240V, use a NEMA 6-20, and also change the breaker to a 20A one.

Comment: Is replacing the breaker necessary, or does it just free up some additional amps for other circuits?  The new unit says it wants 25 amps.

Comment: Breaker **must** match receptacle.

Comment: @user2254963, If you're in the US, the window unit does not call for 25A.  20A is the largest receptacle size used for something like that.  Then it jumps to a giant 30A plug for something like a clothes dryer.

Comment: Breaker **must** match minimum wire gauge.

Comment: I agree with @JPhi1618 that a 25A requirement is unusual for a window AC -- is it perhaps an AC that's designed to be wall-mounted, and you're putting it in a window instead?  And yes, as Harper said, the outlet ampacity must match the breaker, so if you install a 20A receptacle (such as a NEMA 6-20), then you need to change the breaker to a dual pole 20A type.

Comment: There's also a chance the AC uses a 20A circuit, but allows you to bump up to a 25A breaker for the startup surge, as @EdBeal mentions in the comments above.  If you post your AC's instructions (or a link to the model), we can help you figure out how to power it correctly.

Comment: @NateStrickland I have added a picture of the cord on the new unit and a link to it as well.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Please see the picture of the cord of the replacement unit which clearly says 25 amps.  I also added a link to the model of the unit in question.  This is in the US.

Comment: @user2254963, thanks for the pictures.  If that plug is roughly the same size as a common 120v plug, that is actually a 240v/15A plug.  The actual plug/GFCI device on the cord is rated for a max of 25A, but that is not stating the power requirements of the unit.  [This other listing](https://www.johnstonesupply.com/storefront/product-view.ep?pID=B73-753) shows 8.4A for cooling and 14.8A when heating.  There should be a plate on the unit itself that lists electrical requirements in Amps or Watts (Kilowatts, kW).

Comment: @user2254963 If the plug is large, then it is 240V/30A and thats probably larger than any window unit I've seen if it really requires that much power.

Comment: @user2254963, you can ignore the label on the plug itself -- that's what the plug is rated to handle, not the AC itself.  The reason you might have a 25A capable plug/GFI designed for a 15A socket is that for a moment on startup, the AC needs a higher surge of current, and the GFI in the plug must be able to handle this.  Based on the specifications in the page Jphi1618 linked, your AC is designed to draw >15A, and be protected with a 20A breaker (the "fuse size" rating).  So you're gonna want to use a NEMA 6-20 outlet and a 20A breaker.